# Extract text between 2 strings only if another string is present

Tags: bash, sed, awk

I have a quit large XML file that I am trying to modify only certain lines of the file. The lines I want to modify will all contain  in them. On those lines, I want to have only the text between 2 string (in this case those strings are / and ). So lets says I have this in a text file:

```
<title>xxxxxxxxx / xxx</title>
<sys>yyyyyyyyy</sys>
<name>test / extra text</name>
<date>zzzzzzzzz</date>
```

I want to modify it so I get the following:

```
<title>xxxxxxxxx / xxx</title>
<sys>yyyyyyyyy</sys>
<name>test</name>
<date>zzzzzzzzz</date>
```

Can this be accomplished with awk or sed?

Comment: [You can't parse \[X\]HTML with regex](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3776858)

Answer (score 1):

Use an XML parser to parse XML data.

```
# get the current value:
current=$(xmlstarlet sel --template --value-of "//name" file.xml)
# update the value
xmlstarlet ed --inplace --update "//name" --value "${current% /*}" file.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

`sed 's:<name>test / extra text</name>:<name>test</name>:' file.xml`

Or for an in-place substitution, add `-i`:

`sed -i 's:<name>test / extra text</name>:<name>test</name>:' file.xml`